# ffap does not prompt with handle file type indicator like *

Tags: shell, emacs

How can I get `ffap` to ignore the `*` at the end of an executable file?

```
/tmp/check$ ls
somefile*
/tmp/check$ \ls
somefile
```

`ffap` prompts with `/tmp/somefile` for the second but not for the first, I guess because a file literally named `somefile*` does not exist.

Is it possible to introduce some tolerance, such that it prompts with `somefile*` if it exists, else with `somefile` if it does?

Comment: I see that the `ls` man page on GNU/Linux is *terrible* at explaining the `-F` option. Of the other possible suffixes, I *think* you'd only want to support `@` (for symbolic links) in addition to `*` for executables. `/` is obviously already accounted for, and I'm not sure the others are going to be useful with ffap in practice.

Comment: The info manual is more useful. `|` for FIFOs, `=` for sockets, `>` for doors (a Solaris 2.5+ thing apparently).

Comment: Not sure I understand. The * at the end of the filename is not real - you don't have a file named somefile*. What you have is a file called somefile which is executable. The ls command is adding the * as a visual indicator. So ffap appears to be doing the right thing - it is returning the filename of the only matching file on the fs i.e. somefile

Comment: Sorry, I needed to think more before hitting the post button! If you are saying that ffap fails to work at all if you use the ls switch that adds visual indicators, then I would suggest it is a bug in either ffap or in the documentation which should indicate ffap is not compatible with that ls switch.  IMO ffap should ignore the * and return the 'real' file i.e. somefile

Comment: @TimX well `*` is a valid filename character. Consider that (1) cursor is on the string `/tmp/somefile.xyz`, (2) `/tmp/somefile.xyz` does not exist (3) `/tmp/somefile` exists. 

In this case, would you expect `ffap` to prompt for `/tmp/somefile`? This case is similar, so I guess this is no so much a bug as a feature request.

Comment: If there actually is a file with a * in it, then ffap should return that file. However, if the * is NOT part of the filename i.e. is a visual indicator added by the ls command to indicate the file has the execute bit set, then I wouldn't expect ffap to work as technically, there is no file with that character in the file system, but I would hope that ffap is smart enough to handle this correctly i.e. dired uses the -F switch, but ffap knows that somefile* is really somefile and there is no 'real' somefile*. If it can't then docs should warn that -F may cause issues.